# Getting Image through HTML and using Python Code

Tags: html, django, image

I am trying to make a website that gets the user image and uses
facelandmark code(python) to tell the user about user's face shape and etc.

How can I get the imange through html and use the image file in python code and show the result to the user again? Is using django the only way? I have tried to study django in many ways and most of the stuffs I found were not  directly helping on my planning website. Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to directly embed the image in your HTML: Python 3

```html
import base64
data_uri = base64.b64encode(open('Graph.png', 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8')
img_tag = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}">'.format(data_uri)
print(img_tag)
```